# JSON Object Access Value

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON response:

```
{
    "2f2EdLjYHcTx4APbgnlvE2SCXQb2": {
        "name": "test",
        "latitute": 7.4866174,
        "longitute": 80.3637889
    },
    "pJua8KSpMwSXiSlWJcDE4sEkOuZ2": {
        "name": "akalanka",
        "latitute": 7.4866198,
        "longitute": 80.3638016
    }
}
```

How can i access name, latitude and longitute in JavaScript?

I tried using this method, it shows data but i can't access the properties I need:

```
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://localhost:3000/get/json", false );
    xmlHttp.send();
    var data=xmlHttp.responseText;

    var x=[];

    x=JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    // x=data.length;


    console.log(x);
    // latitute=x.latitute;
    // longitute=x.longitute;
    z=15;
    myMap();
}
```

Comment: @Bravo the JSON is absolutely valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems in the code:

1) You are using xmlHttp incorrectly.

You are sending the request but parsing the result directly (without waiting for the request to succeed).

```
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://localhost:3000/get/json", false );
xmlHttp.send();

xmlHttp.onload = function () {
 // Request finished. Do processing here.
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

2) You need to use the key to access the 'latitute'.

```
Object.keys(x).forEach(field => {
  console.log(x[field].latitute);
  console.log(x[field].longitute);
});
```

So it should look like this:

```
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://localhost:3000/get/json", false );
xmlHttp.send();

xmlHttp.onload = function () {
  var x = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
  Object.keys(x).forEach(field => {
    console.log(x[field].latitute);
    console.log(x[field].longitute);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please confirm that you already get responseText by using `onreadystate` method.

After that, please try with this.

```
var responseText = `{"2f2EdLjYHcTx4APbgnlvE2SCXQb2":{"name":"test","latitute":7.4866174,"longitute":80.3637889},"pJua8KSpMwSXiSlWJcDE4sEkOuZ2":{"name":"akalanka","latitute":7.4866198,"longitute":80.3638016}}`;

var x = JSON.parse(responseText);

console.log(x);

Object.keys(x).forEach(field => {
  console.log(x[field].name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks your approach was also correct, i was tested it. thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

Beware your properties are misspelled `longitute`, `latitute`... *te*? Should be ***de***

I'd convert the nonstandard UID-as-keys to a simple **Array**.
Quick example using fetch API:

```js
const myMap = (data) => {
  console.log(`lat:${data.latitute}, lng:${data.longitute}`)
};

const fetchMapData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsbin.com/mijopocunu/js');
  const json = await response.json();
  const dataArr = Object.keys(json).map(k => (json[k].id = k, json[k]));
  dataArr.forEach(myMap);
};

fetchMapData();
```

Comment: Thanks, your code also work and i'm able to access the data  :)